# window.setInterval not working on angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this small piece of code that uses [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) method:

```
function MyController($scope) {
    $scope.clock = new Date();
    var updateClock = function() {
        $scope.clock = new Date();
    };
    setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
};
```

and html as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        <h1>Hello {{ clock }}!</h1>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, `setInterval` in `MyController` does not update time. 
Where possibly is wrong here ?

It works this way according to a book :

```
function MyController($scope) {
    $scope.clock = new Date();
    var updateClock = function() {
        $scope.clock = new Date();
    };
    setInterval(function() {
        $scope.$apply(updateClock);
    }, 1000);
    updateClock();
};
```

Why is that and what goes wrong without using @scope.$apply ?

Comment: Will you please give a js fiddle link for this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the angular [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) service.

```
function($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.clock = new Date();
    var updateClock = function() {
        $scope.clock = new Date();
    };
    $interval(updateClock, 1000);
}
```

Comment: I understand I could use that and is the preferable way to do it, but could you please throw some light why did it now work with setInterval ? Infact, if instead of passing updateClock directly to setInterval, if I had  done $scope.@apply(updateclock), it works. I am trying to know the reason after this.

Comment: Inside of a traditional `setInterval` function, Angular does not know about your updates, and thus, you must `$apply()` it yourself.  For example, you could leave it how it was and in your `updateClock` method call `$apply` after you change the value to tell Angular you've updated.  Instead, using the built in `$interval` (or `$timeout`) functions, this work is done for you.  Additionally, these return a promise, so you can actually do work on them via ` .then()` if you'd like.

Comment: Why is updateClock without parenthesis, like this: updateClock()?

Comment: @munchschair that's the syntax used for $interval

Answer (score 5):

If you use the JS ***setInterval()*** then you will need $scope.$apply() to your method.

```
var updateClock = function() {
        $scope.clock = new Date();
        $scope.$apply();
    };
```

The better solution is to use ***$interval*** (angular)

```
$interval(updateClock, 1000);
```