# I define one countdown function, but no output?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

html, this is my code, following is the detail. My purpose is realized countdown function with using angularJS.

```js
var app = angular.module('myCountDown', []);

app.controller("Countdown",function($scope){

$scope.start = function(){
var temp = $scope.inputValue;

setInterval(function(){
if(temp<1){
 return ;
}
temp -= 1;
$scope.count = temp;
console.log($scope.count);   
},1000);
}
})
```

```html
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myCountDown">
 <div ng-controller="Countdown">
  <input type="text" ng-model="inputValue">
  <button ng-click="start()">开始</button>
  <input type="text" ng-model="count">
 </div>
 <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have print the result in console,but no output in web page.

thank you!

Comment: You should use `$interval` service for this [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31207513/setinterval-and-angularjs)

Answer (score 2):

Use $scope.$apply() to see your changes OR use **`$interval`** which is recommended for angular instead of **`setTimeout`**  .

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('myCountDown', []);
app.controller("Countdown", function($scope, $interval) {
  $scope.start = function() {
    var temp = $scope.inputValue;
    $interval(function() {
      if (temp < 1) {
        return;
      }
      temp -= 1;
      $scope.count = temp;
      console.log($scope.count);
    }, 1000);
  }
})
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myCountDown">
 <div ng-controller="Countdown">
  <h1> {{count}}</h1>
  <input type="text" ng-model="inputValue">
  <button ng-click="start()">开始</button>
    {{count}}
  <input type="text" ng-model="count">
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval` will run out of angular's scope. you can use `$interval`.
also remember to clear previous `interval` before create a new one.

refer below example.

```js
var app = angular.module('myCountDown', []);

app.controller("Countdown", function($scope, $interval) {
  
  $scope.start = function() {
    var temp = $scope.inputValue;
    if ($scope.sampleInterval) {
      $interval.cancel($scope.sampleInterval);
    }
    $scope.sampleInterval = $interval(function() {
      if (temp < 1) {
        return;
      }
      temp -= 1;
      $scope.count = temp;
      console.log($scope.count);
    }, 1000);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myCountDown" ng-app="myCountDown">
  <div ng-controller="Countdown">
    <input type="text" ng-model="inputValue">
    <button ng-click="start()">开始</button>
    <input type="text" ng-model="count">
  </div>
  <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know how to solve this problem.
we can modify the js file.

```js
var app = angular.module('myCountDown', []);

app.controller("Countdown",function($scope){

$scope.start = function(){
var temp = $scope.inputValue;

setInterval(function(){
if(temp<1){
 return ;
}
temp -= 1;
$scope.count = temp;
$scope.$apply();
console.log($scope.count);   
},1000);
}
})
```

we need to trigger angular application by hand with using $scope.$apply();

Comment: no need to post a new answer, you can directly mark existing one