# setInterval function isn't working with angular

Tags: angularjs, setinterval

`setInterval` function isn't working in my AngularJS project

[image]

Comment: Try using $interval https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

Comment: please post your code instead of an image, and be more descriptive on how  it was not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [window.setInterval not working on angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31207513/window-setinterval-not-working-on-angularjs)

Comment: thanks a lot. well, next time I'll be put the question as you mention.

Comment: @Satya You can always [edit] your post and include the actual code (Not a screenshot) - It will probably revert some down votes. Please consider accepting one of the answers if you find it helpful (By clicking on the green "V" icon next to it)

Answer (score 2):

Try using the angular service $interval.

```
    app.controller('MyController',['$scope','$interval',function($scope,$interval) {
        $scope.person = {name: 'Satya'};

        var updateClock = function() {
            $scope.clock = new Date();
        }

        $interval(updateClock,1000);
    }]);
```

Comment: Finally, a proper answer!

Answer (score 0):

Alright this is a weird problem but by creating a new function tag you lose the $scope variable. Next time please paste the code rather than an image though. Try this

```
var timer = setInterval(()=>{
    $scope.$apply(updateClock);
}, 1000);
updateClock(); 
....
```

Or use the built in Angular functions for setInterval, [Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval).

Answer (score 0):

> Don't use `setInterval()`. Use Angular `$interval` service .

Comment: `$interval` is not a method. It is a service